# htaccess shows 404 error rather than finding index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some issues with a shady URL rewriting

I want to turn `http://localhost:81/es/index.php` into `http://localhost:81/index.php?lengua=es` with my `.htaccess` in order to help the page SEO

This is my current `.htaccess`

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.(log|ini|htaccess)$">
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
FallbackResource "index.php"

RewriteRule ^(en|es|pt)?/?(.*)?$ $2?idioma=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have checked that they work with [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and they're working as expected but when I browse the page it shows a "File not found." error (I do have a `index.php`, I do not have a `es/index.php`)

[image: file not found error]

Since my output URL is `http://localhost:81/index.php?lengua=es` I don't understand why is it not working

Comment: Is there anything in your server's error_log file for these requests?

Comment: Is this rule doing anything? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled?? (Is mod_rewrite enabled?)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Error/apache logs only show the 404 error
Error log outputs:
`code`[Wed Nov 10 19:12:09.685194 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 93:tid 140126253808360] [client 172.24.0.1:41464] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown', referer: http://localhost:81/index_traducciones.php`code`
"/index_traducciones.php" works perfectly when not using /es in the url

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Also, the rewrite rule is a remain from previous tests it doesn't change the outcome, it's still there because I sometimes change the regex of the rule while testing (I just commented it, same result)

Comment: @MrWhite Same as Stephen, is a remain from previous tests, I have mod rewrite on, my current full .htaccess is:
<FilesMatch ".*\.(log|ini|htaccess)$">
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
FallbackResource "index.php"
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "\/en\/|\/es\/|\/pt\/"
RewriteRule ^(en|es|pt)?/?(.*)?$ $2?idioma=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Why do you want `index.php` to be in your URL at all?   I'd recommend hiding that from users.   I'd want `example.com/es/` to be the URL rather than `example.com/es/index.php`   The reason for index documents is to power the root URL without actually showing the filename for the index document in the URL.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller index.php is just an example, I need to access the different php files  that conform our pages, that's why i just dont do something like /index.php?idioma=$1&page=$2

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking this in four rewrite rules:

```sh
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to add the trailing slash to language directory
# http://example.com/es  > http://example.com/es/
RewriteRule ^/?(en|es|pt)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Redirect to remove `index.php`
# http://example.com/es/index.php  > http://example.com/es/
RewriteRule ^/?(en|es|pt)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Handle requests for the base language directory
# http://example.com/es/  > http://example.com/index.php?idioma=es
RewriteRule ^/?(en|es|pt)/$ /index.php?idioma=$1 [QSA,L]

# Handle requests for php files within the language directory
# http://example.com/es/foo.php  > http://example.com/foo.php?idioma=es
RewriteRule ^/?(en|es|pt)/(.+\.php)$ /$2?idioma=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I would remove `RewriteBase /` because I believe that is the default in the root `.htaccess` file anyway.

I would remove `FallbackResource "index.php"` because you shouldn't need it based on the examples you have provided.  If you keep it, the examples in the documentation show it starting with a slash:  `FallbackResource /index.php`.  You should also test without it because it has the potential to conflict with the rewrite rules.

I always like to start rewrite rules with an optional slash `^/?` (rather than just `^`) so that they can be used both in `.htaccess` and in `httpd.conf` without modifications.

The rule in the question makes *everything* optional including the language code.  Rather than `(en|es|pt)?` my rules use `(en|es|pt)` so that they *don't* match if the language code isn't in the URL.

Rather than make the slash after the language directory optional, my rules do different things when it is present and when it is not.

In your rule `(.*)?` is *exactly* equivalent to the simpler `(.*)`.  I changed it to `(.*\.php)` so that it only matches PHP files.